# Docker image stuck on bundling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, bundler

I've been trying to build my Docker image:

```
docker build -t <tag> -f Dockerfile.production .
```

However, this hangs while bundling.
I have tried bundling with:

```
DEBUG_RESOLVER=true bundle install --verbose
```

Running bundle on my host machine works fine - only the Docker image has this problem.

Attached is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM cimg/ruby:2.7.4-node

LABEL maintainer=budgeneration@gmail.com
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

USER root

RUN sudo apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y nodejs npm libvips-tools libsodium-dev \
  apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common \
  librocksdb-dev \
  libsnappy-dev \
  python3-distutils \
  rsyslog --no-install-recommends

# Other tools not related to building by still required.
RUN sudo apt-get install -y ffmpeg gifsicle

USER circleci

# Install all gems first.
# This hits the warm cache if unchanged so bundling is faster.
COPY Gemfile* /tmp/
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN gem install sassc-rails -v 2.1.2
RUN gem install bulma-rails -v 0.9.1
RUN bundle config set without 'development test' \
  && bundle install --verbose \
  && bundle binstubs railties

# Remove yarn (the other yarn)
RUN apt-get purge cmdtest
RUN yarn global add mjml

WORKDIR /sapco

# First we copy just Yarn files, to run yarn install
COPY package.json /sapco
COPY yarn.lock /sapco
RUN yarn install

WORKDIR /sapco

# Now copy everything
COPY . /sapco

EXPOSE 3000
```

Any tips to try to debug this further?

Comment: *However, this hangs while bundling* Probably a good idea to be more specific. Which specific command causes the error? What's the error message? Might be relevant information... what do you think?

Comment: There is no error message because it hangs - doesn't complete. The command use it listed right below that line.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this issue but not sure why:

I changed my base image file to `FROM circleci/ruby:2.7.4-buster-node` and the bundling step continues fine.